# $window.ga is undefined in AngularJS event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I am trying to add **Google Analytics** to my web SPA app. I have added GA script to the `index.html` file:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
</script>
```

And here is my `"$stateChangeSuccess"` event:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    var url = API_URL+$location.url()
    console.log(url)
    $window.ga('send', 'pageview', { page: url }); // line 54
});
```

Here is what I get:

```
>>http://localhost:3030/search
>>angular.js:9959 TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at app.run.js:54
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$broadcast (angular.js:12874)
    at $state.transitionTo.$state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition (angular-ui-router.js:3218)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11485)
    at angular.js:11571
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12595)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12407)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12699)
    at done (angular.js:8287)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:8499)
```

From this error I can get that `$window.ga()` is `undefined`

What did I do wrong and how can I make it work?

Comment: Not sure if that is the issue but try properly injecting the `$window` object - `funtion($window, event, toState, ...)`.

Comment: @TadeášPeták this is event. Injections are made in the `.run` function

Comment: Maybe you need to use `none ` instead of auto for your localhost calls.  in your `ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto'); `. Local calls may cause problems. Mine is like `...,'@(Request.IsLocal ? "none" : "auto")'`

Comment: The question is old but if you still need there is an alternative tracking method here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Comment: I know its old question. But may be its due to adBlocker check out if you have enabled adBlocker.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `var url = API_URL+$location.url()` this line working good?

Where you initialized the `API_URL`?

and also where you initialized the `$location`?

So you may be got that error from `API_URL` and `$location`.(but am not sure)

So you need declare the `API_URL` value  and inject the location in your `$scope.$on` event.

Your code should be

```
 $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function($location){
      var API_URL ="Your Url";//Put your url
        var url = API_URL + $location.url();
        console.log(url);
        $window.ga('send', 'pageview', { page: url }); // line 54
    });
```

### Edit

try this below code

You have miss initializing the $window

```
 $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function($location, $window){
            var API_URL = "Your Url"; // Put your url
            var url = API_URL + $location.url();
            console.log(url);
            $window.ga('send', 'pageview', { page: url }); // line 54
        });
```

Comment: So your URL is correct? did you check the value with using breakpoint?

Comment: yes it is correct, and error says that `$window.ga('send', 'pageview', { page: url });` => `undefined is not a function`

Comment: did you check the values of `$window`?

Comment: Okay, You have missed to initialized the `$window.`

Comment: WHAT?? `$window.localStorage` works. And if I have missed to initialized the `$window` I would get another error!

Comment: Yea I'm also curious about `var url = API_URL+$location.url()` I doubt that it works :D